# nodejs + mongodb: Modify existing document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert-update

I store balances of users in mongo. Now I want to mathematically add to an existing balance as in `balance = balance + amount`. I am looping over multiple values in a function which gets an array of balances that are to be updated. The following

```
UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({ address: accounts[c].address }, 
  { balance: accounts[c].amount }, 
  (error, user) => { 
    // do stuff
  }
);
```

What I want is something like:

```
  { balance: user.amount + accounts[c].amount },
```

I also tried to first read the value and in the callback function do another `findOneAndUpdate`, unfortunately the callback handler does not have the right index `c` and thus accesses the wrong element in `accounts[c].amount`.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you want to update `balance` field with `accounts[c].amount`?

Comment: no, I want to add the amount. as in `balance = balance + accounts[c].amount`. NB: With `add` I mean the mathematical operation on numbers, not adding an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `{ balance: accounts[c].amount }` try `{ $inc: { balance: accounts[c].amount }}`. It should just increment `balance` by `accounts[c].amount`.